# Наследование от абстрактного класса (вопросы по учебному примеру)

Tags: java, наследование, методы, конструктор

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с тем как работает наследование в контексте работы с абстрактными классами и их наследниками, вызове методов и конструкторов тех и других, разобрав со мной конкретный пример.

В учебном примере есть абстрактный класс **Animal**, и есть его потомок **Monkey**.

```
abstract public class Animal {

    public int nLegs = 0;
    public void numLegs(int nLegs) {
        this.nLegs = nLegs;
    }


    public abstract int getLegs();

    //Constructor
    public Animal (int nLegs) {
        numLegs(nLegs)
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Monkey extends Animals {

    public int getLegs(){
        return this.nLegs;
    }
    public monkey(){
        super(2);
    }

    public void saySome(){
        System.out.println("Hello, I am a monkey!");
    }

}
```

В **Animal** есть `переменная nLegs` (количество ног), `метод numLegs`, задающий значение этой переменной, `геттер getLegs`, для получения ее значения и `конструктор`, задающий значение `переменной nLegs` с помощью `метода numLegs`.

В **Monkey** мы `реализуем геттер` (абстрактный метод необходимо реализовать), `создаем конструктор`, который вызывает `конструктор Animal`, присваивая его локальной переменной значение `2`, а так же пишем дополнительный `метод saySome`, выводящий в консоль строку.

Все правильно? Тогда идем дальше:

В главном классе пишем:

```
public class MainClass{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Animal jay = new Monkey ();
        System.out.println(jay.nLegs);

       /* jay.saySome()*/
        ((Monkey) jay).saySome();

     }
}
```

Вопросы:

> 1. Что означает такое выражение при создании объекта jay? jay не может принадлежать абсрактому классу, знаит он принадлежит **Monkey**,
>      но как тогда читать логику этого выражения (сейчас я читаю `Animal jay
>      = new Monkey ();` как  `Класса Animal объект jay = новый объект jay класса Monkey`
> 2. Почему закомментенный мной метод `jay.saySome()` не работает? Почему работает `((Monkey) jay).saySome();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Геттер не переназначается, а реализуется. В `Animal` он лишь объявлен, но не реализован. В `Monkey` вы его реализуете. Используйте правильные термины, они ведь не просто так существуют. Аналогично с конструктором, он не "работает как конструктор `Animal`", а он внутри себя лишь вызывает конструктор `Animal`.

Выражение `Animal jay = new Monkey();` означает что вы создаете объект `Monkey` и присваиваете его в переменную типа `Animal`, так как `Monkey` это тоже `Animal`. И дальше вы работаете с переменной `jay` как с `Animal`, при этом в голове зная что это на самом деле ещё и `Monkey`.

Закомментированный метод не работает именно потому, что `jay` - это обобщенный `Animal`, без уточнения. А в классе `Animal` нет метода `saySome`. Но поскольку вы знаете, что `jay` является `Monkey`, вы явно приводите тип и вызываете метод из класса `Monkey`

**UPD**

Ответы на вопросы из коммантария:

2) Для объекта класса потомка наследуются все поля класса предка и объект класса потомка является как объектом класса потомка, так и объектом класса предка (я не вдаюсь сейчас в тонкости всяких getClass(), вам это на текущем этапе не нужно знать). Класс при объявлении переменной можно понимать как тип, да.

3) Он не может наследовать обе структуры. Одна у него своя, собственная, описанная в классе `Monkey`, а наследует он поля и методы класса `Animal`.

4) `Monkey jay = new Monkey();` - так можно, почему нет. Вопрос в том что вы хотите получить. К примеру, если у вас есть ещё один класс, `Elephant extends Animal`, в нем также реализован метод `getLegs`, и вы захотите в своем коде собрать всех животных в один список, а затем узнать сколько у кого ног:

```
List<Animal> animals = fillList(); //Заполним список как-нибудь
for(Animal animal : animals){
    System.out.println(animal.getLegs());
}
```

В этом куске кода вам абсолютно неважно где там слон, а где обезьяна, вы просто знаете что у них общего (у всех есть ноги) и пользуетесь этим. В случае если внутри цикла `animal` окажется слоном, то вызовется `getLegs` класса `Elephant`, а если `animal` будет обезьяной, то вызовется `getLegs` класса `Monkey`.

Comment: 1) Спасибо за поправку в терминах, учусь. 

2) То есть родительский класс, передавая по наследству свои поля и методы потомку, автоматически становится "типом" переменной, которой присваиваются объекты потомка? Как типом даных переменной (int, String) но созданным пользователем?  

3) Как понимать "при этом в голове зная что это на самом деле ещё и Monkey." - объект jay наследует обе структуры от родителя и потомка, или тоько от потомка Monkey (который реализует унаследованное от Animal)?

4) А почему нельзя так Monkey jay = new Monkey(); - вед Monkey уже прописан как наследник Animal?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Обновил ответ